# Android Kotlin "withTimeout" coroutine how to handle exception

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using retrofit2 to call API with kotlin coroutines but the API has status code 200, 400 and 700.
When request the API and response status code was 400 or 700, which the "withTimeout" coroutine can be exception crash.
I want to handle status code 400 and 700 response message with "withTimeout" coroutine or how to customize "CoroutineScope" thanks.

This is my code

```
 suspend fun getLogin() {
    try {
        var result = withTimeout(5_000) {  // <----this line can be crashed with http code 700
            accountService.getLogin(
               LoginRequest() // request data
            ) // retrofit
        }
        when (result.state_code) { // api response state code
            200 -> {
                 Timber.i("Create account got data: ${result.source}")
            }
            400 -> {
                 //....... handle this status code error
            }
            700 -> {
               //....... handle this status code error
            }
        }
    } catch (e: ApiError) {
        throw ApiError("Unable to login", e)
    }
}
```

Error message

```
2020-04-26 22:55:10.384 28895-28895/com.mgear.mednetapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mgear.mednetapp, PID: 28895
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 700  
    at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:150)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, ***SocketTimeoutException***  should be handled, but here you can handle the generic ***Exception*** here and later check whether your exception is **SocketTimeoutException, JsonSyntaxException, UnknownHostException, ConnectException or others.**

So, you can try this.

```
suspend fun getLogin() {
 try {
 //Your api call code here.
 }catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStacktrace();
    //throw ApiError("Unable to login", e)
 }
}
```